# How to convert an array of map in Firestore to a List of map Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build an app with Flutter and Firestore, but I am confused by the way I have to implement my data from Firestore  to Dart language, so the problem is that I have an array of the map in my Firestore, each element in the array represent a map like this

[image: screenshot]

And in my app, I want to represent the data from Firestore to something readable, I declare a class like this:

```
class rest_model{
String rest_name;
GeoPoint rest_lat_long;
GeoPoint city_lat_long;
var rest_address = new Map();
var rest_food_list = new List<Map>();
```

I know how to convert the other into variables or readable, I use this approach:

```
rest_model.map(dynamic obj){

this.rest_name = obj['rest_name'];
this.rest_lat_long = obj['rest_lat_long'];
this.city_lat_long = obj['city_lat_long'];
this.rest_address['rest_email'] = obj['rest_address']['rest_email'];
this.rest_address['rest_phone']=obj['rest_address']['rest_phone'];
this.rest_address['rest_website'] = obj['rest_address']['rest_website'];
}

rest_model.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map){

this.rest_name = map['rest_name'];
this.rest_lat_long = map['rest_lat_long'];
this.city_lat_long = map['city_lat_long'];
this.rest_address['rest_email'] = map['rest_address']['rest_email'];
this.rest_address['rest_phone']=map['rest_address']['rest_phone'];
this.rest_address['rest_website'] = map['rest_address']['rest_website'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toMap(){
var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
map['rest_name'] = rest_name ;
map['rest_lat_long'] = rest_lat_long;
map['city_lat_long'] = city_lat_long;
map['rest_address'] = rest_address.values;
}
```

But I don't know how to convert the array of the map `rest_food_list`.

Please anyone can help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Create a class in dart similar to that in firestore1. Create a class in dart similar to that in firestore. I have a Post class in Dart and an array of posts in firestore. 
   [Firestore Array of Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNzF0.png)
2. My class in Dart is like below

```
class Main{
  final String userName;
  final List<Post> post;

  Main({this.userName, this.post});
}

class Post {
  final String postImg;
  final int likes;
  final String description;

  Post({this.postImg, this.description, this.likes});
}
```

When I am fetching the data from firestore, since firestore has array so you can convert that array of Map like this in dart.

```
//fetch firestore documents by getDocuments()
data.documents.forEach((doc) {
      Main main = new Main(
          userImg: doc.data["user_image"],
          post: List<Post>.from(doc.data["posts"].map((item) {
            return new Post(
                likes: item["likes"],
                postImg: item["image"],
                description: item["description"]);
          })));
      //add the main data object to List;
    }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your help , it really work but work with the String **food_name** , and when i add the other fields , it doesn't work , I tried to rename the fields in Firestore collection ,by deleting the array and create new one with new names for the fields name , but I don't know why it doesn't work the other and only work with one field **food_name** .. I don't know really

Comment: Should I use another collection for the list of food  ,and make the id of restaurant as a reference collection in the new collection

Comment: It also unlocked me on roadblocks (even in 2020 ;-) ), so thank you for that!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do it before but you can try this:

```
rest_model.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
  this.rest_name = map['rest_name'];
  this.rest_lat_long = map['rest_lat_long'];
  this.city_lat_long = map['city_lat_long'];
  this.rest_address['rest_email'] = map['rest_address']['rest_email'];
  this.rest_address['rest_phone'] = map['rest_address']['rest_phone'];
  this.rest_address['rest_website'] = map['rest_address']['rest_website'];
  this.rest_food_list = map['rest_food_list'].map((Map<String, dynamic> restFood) {
    Map<String, dynamic> food = {
      'calories_plate': restFood['calories_plate'],
      'food_name': restFood['food_name'],
      'price': restFood['price'],
    };
    return food;
  }).toList();
}
```

Comment: No , I didn't mean that , I meant  , I have a collection in firestore called restaurant , and each document in this collection have these fields ( rest_name "String ", rest_lat_long "Geopoint" , and  rest_food_list which is an array and each elemnet in the array is a map , and the map has three key,values  .. I know how to convert the other fileds but don't know how to convert the array of map

Comment: I meant convert an array of map in firestore to a list of map in dart , and vise-versa  @hoangquyy

Comment: @SunaArun I have edited it, you can try it, sorry I misunderstood

Comment: It's ok .. Thanks for your help , but didn't work out with me .. What should I do @hoangquyy

Comment: But it's only accept the string type, so I changed all the other types to String  .. Thanks again