# Flutter/Dart firestore returns LinkedMap - How to use this?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In `firestore`, I have an `array` of (simple) `map`s.

When getting this data into `Flutter/Dart`, using the `cloud_firestore` package as follows:

```
    Stream<T> documentStream<T>({
      required String path,
      required T Function(Map<String, dynamic>? data, String documentID) builder})
      {
        final DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> reference =
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
        final Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshots =
            reference.snapshots();
        return snapshots.map((snapshot) => builder(snapshot.data(), snapshot.id));
      }
```

and consuming this e.g. as follows:

```
documentStream(
  path: 'firestore_path_doc',
  builder: (data, documentId) {
    final x = data['array_of_maps'];
    print(x[0].runtimeType); // gives LinkedMap<String, dynamic>
    final y = x as List<Map<String, String>>; // fails
    final y1 = x[0] as Map<String, String>; // fails
  },
);
```

fails.

I cannot find a way to convert the map inside this array to a normal map.
In fact, I can barely find any info on `LinkedMap`. After digging, I see its in the `js` (https://pub.dev/packages/js) package, but it's internal there, not supposed to be exposed.

If I had a `map` in `firestore`, it converts easily to a `Map<String, String>` in `dart`. But a `map` inside an `array` arrives as a `LinkedMap`.

How can I work this `LinkedMap`? I cannot even iterate over it, since it is not recognised at compile time, even if I try to import `js`.

thx

Comment: Would `final y1 = x[0] as Map<String, dynamic>` work for you?

Comment: @jamesdlin The VS debugger literally shows 'LinkedMap' which is an internal type in the js package

Comment: @AndreyGordeev No, that does not work either. Same error. `x[0].runtimeType` shows as `LinkedMap<String, dynamic>` and `x[0] as Map<String, dynamic>` fails

Answer (score 3):

`x[0]` type is `Map<String, dynamic>`. You're trying to cast it to `Map<String, String>`, which would obviously fail.
You can do that manually though:

```dart
final x = data['array_of_maps'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
final myMap = x[0].map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.toString()));
```

Comment: No, that does not work either. Same error. `x[0].runtimeType` shows as `LinkedMap<String, dynamic>` and `x[0] as Map<String, dynamic>` fails

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work following the answer to this: [How to convert an array of map in Firestore to a List of map Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178478/how-to-convert-an-array-of-map-in-firestore-to-a-list-of-map-dart)

Basically by using a `class` for the inner `map` instead of a generic `Map`.