# How to convert firebase map objects to a local list in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to cache a firebase document filed to a local List. But I don't know how to do that.

Here is firebase document field I want to cache
[image]

This is the list I want:

```
List theListIwant = [
      {'aed': true},
      {'bet': false},
      {'med': true},
      {'zed': true},
    ];
```

DocumentSnapshot:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stores').doc(storeData.user.uid).snapshots()
```

I am stuck here:

```
List medicineList = (snapshot.data!
                            .get('meds') as Map)
                            .entries
                            .map((e) => null)
```

Comment: Have you gone through this similar stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178478/how-to-convert-an-array-of-map-in-firestore-to-a-list-of-map-dart)

Answer (score 0):

First create a map from Firebase

and then

map convert to list

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as you can see my question, I was already trying it and stucked now

Answer (score 0):

your **DocumentSnapshot**

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('stores').doc(storeData.user.uid).collection('meds').snapshots()
```

Map dataa

```
snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> data =
                        document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    List theListIwant = [
                       {'aed': data["aed"]},
                       {'bet': data["bet"]},
                       {'med': data["med"]},
                       {'zed': data["zed"]},
                    ];
                  }
```

Comment: I don't think this is gonna work. because 'meds' is not a subcollection, it is a field with type of Map. But thank you for your help